# Unable to install python berkeleydb access on osx

Tags: python, macos

I installed python 2.6 on my mac (which ships with 2.5, and I am going crazy in working with 2.6) Everything has been installed on `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/`. Now I want to install the python BerkeleyDB module, but it goes syntax error during the build:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/extsrc
gcc -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DPYBSDDB_STANDALONE=1 -I~/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c extsrc/_bsddb.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/extsrc/_bsddb.o
extsrc/_bsddb.c:232: error: syntax error before 'DB_ENV'
extsrc/_bsddb.c:232: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
extsrc/_bsddb.c:239: error: syntax error before '}' token
extsrc/_bsddb.c:239: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
extsrc/_bsddb.c:245: error: syntax error before 'DBEnvObject'
extsrc/_bsddb.c:245: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
extsrc/_bsddb.c:258: error: syntax error before '}' token
extsrc/_bsddb.c:258: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
<and so on>
extsrc/_bsddb.c:5915: error: 'DB_OLD_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this function)
extsrc/_bsddb.c:5916: error: 'DB_RUNRECOVERY' undeclared (first use in this function)
extsrc/_bsddb.c:5917: error: 'DB_VERIFY_BAD' undeclared (first use in this function)
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/Ye/YeXcn-oIE7ybm-TS4yB8c++++TQ/-Tmp-//cclJF2Xy.out
```

Google does not help.

Comment: Are you building BerkelyDB from a configure script?

Comment: I compiled berkeleydb from configure, as downloaded form oracle.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the module. What arguments to configure did you use? I think you need to modify the include path, i.e. something like `--with-python=Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/`.

Comment: The fact is that the compile line contains the proper path to the include dir. I'm trying with fink as you suggested. It's 5 in the morning here and I am rather annoyed. I have no interest in BDB at all, I just want to do an experiment with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may save you a lot of time to reinstall python using fink or macports, then get the berkley package from either.

Comment: macports is more comprehensive, I just mention fink so I'm not playing favorites.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Python 2.6 installer for OS X from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.2/) includes bsddb.  Why build your own?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

easy_install bsddb3

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for python2.5 easy_install didn't work for me

```
# get berkeley db
sudo port install db44

# download and untar bsddb3-4.8.1 and cd to the directory
sudo python setup.py --berkeley-db-incdir=/opt/local/include/db44 --berkeley-db-libdir=/opt/local/lib/db44 build

# test program test.py ran but don't know what it did
python test.py

# install
sudo python setup.py --berkeley-db-incdir=/opt/local/include/db44 --berkeley-db-libdir=/opt/local/lib/db44 install

# import as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing `lxml`. Try this for berkeleydb:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install bsddb3
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mavericks/Yosemite (can use newer versions like db53 too):

```
sudo port install db51
sudo ln -sf /opt/local/include/db51/ /opt/local/lib/db51/include
sudo ln -sf /opt/local/lib/db51/ /opt/local/lib/db51/lib
sudo BERKELEYDB_DIR=/opt/local/lib/db51 ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install bsddb3
```